# Python getting a url request to work with special characters

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, special-characters

```
url = ("websitetogetdatafrom/vandcenter syd/sites/"
       "{}/histdata0/youngest".format('vestre boulevard f77r370 -ny logger 1'))
stuff = "\"select\": [\"{}\"]".format('ui2')
full_url = quote(url + "{{" + stuff + "}}")
print(full_url)
payload = {}
headers = {'Authorization': 'autherization token'}
response = requests.request("GET", full_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.json())
```

I am trying to get a timestamp of data, I cannot get the data as the url that comes out:
https://websitetogetdatafrom/vandcenter%20syd/sites/vestre%20boulevard%20f77r370%20-ny%20logger%201/histdata0/youngest{"select":%20["ui2"]}

The last bit {"select":%20["ui2"]} does not get turned into the url. I am looking into uirllib.parse but find it quite complicated. So was wondering if you people know how to turn a string with special characters like { and " into a functioning url request.

Using python 3.7 with requests library.

Comment: What should the URL look like?

Comment: Yes that answers my question thank you. That helped. I had some extra problems with the json payload having to be defined in the url string and not as a payload. But a collegue helped me with that bit. Thanks again